# Limit scope of method for child implementations

Tags: c#, .net

I hope this isn't a duplicate but I can't find one via Google or SO search. If I want to force the accessibility for a method's implementation of an overridden method to be `protected`, is my only option to either create as `abstract` or `protected virtual`? I know that interfaces specify the declaration but leave the accessibility/scope to the class implementation but I'd like to be sure.

I'd like to know/be certain of if the only way to limit the scope of a method is via a `abstract` \ `protected virtual` to give semantics of "this applies to the class implementation or the child override implementation".

A code sample to illustrate. I know I can do the following and limit the scope of an implementation like so;

```
public class BaseClass
{
     protected virtual void OnlyMeOrChildrenCanDoAction()
     {
         // leave empty as current class is structural/conceptual
         // but child instances may need it
     }
}
```

By doing the above I guarantee that child implementations can only `override` `OnlyMeorChildrenCanDoAction()`as `protected` but not `public`.

But is there another way of limiting to `protected` without resorting to `abstract` or `protected virtual`? An example of creating a method like this is `Object.Finalize()` as seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.110).aspx).

Or, to invert the question somewhat, why would you create a method as `protected virtual` unless to ensure that any implementations were limited in scope? Or is there another way to do the same?

Comment: I'm having a very hard time understanding what you are trying to ask.  I would suggest adding some code examples.  I was not the downvoter though

Comment: I am still pretty lost.

Comment: @maccettura if I create a method `protected virtual` I guarantee that only child implementations can use the method as `protected`. I can't have a child implementation override it as `public`. Is the approach above the only way of doing this?

Comment: @DiskJunky - I'm really lost too. Any methods declared as `protected abstract` or `protected virtual` can only ever be overridden in a child class as `protected override` - this can't change. And the method can only ever be called by the class or the children anyway. Are you getting confused with the `new` (shadowing, not constructor) keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the meaning and use of `virtual`. You can *only* override a method in the parent class if it is declared virtual. The override method in the child class must have the same visibility as the method in the parent class.

Implementations of methods declared in interfaces are always `public`.

Declaring a method `abstract` has the same effect as declaring it `virtual`, except you do not implement it in your class and any concrete classes that derive from your class must implement it.

Comment: The scope of implementations of an interface are left up to the implementer and are not `public` unless the implementer declares so (as far as I'm aware). This doesn't answer my question though: is there another way of limiting scope in a child implementation?

Comment: "To implement an interface member, the corresponding member of the implementing class must be public, non-static, and have the same name and signature as the interface member." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/

Comment: I stand corrected. This does answer that an interface is not the way to go

Comment: Your question does not make sense the way you're asking it. It is not possible to change the visibility of a method by overriding it.

Comment: That's the crux of my question - is it impossible given the current C# spec? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: It's not just possible, it's mandatory. I don't know why you don't want to use `protected virtual`, but there is no overriding of methods without `virtual`, and if you want `protected` then you should use `protected`.

Comment: Well given the example of `Object.Finalize()`, you'd create `protected virtual` to allow implementations of any object to clean themselves up and tie it into the GC. `Object` itself doesn't care as there isn't anything to clean and an interface isn't the way to go as an object may or may not implement it. By specifying `Object.Finalize()`, you give a way of any child implementations to clean up what they need as and when they're needed. My curiousity was as to whether there was another approach possible given the language spec

Comment: "an interface isn't the way to go as an object may or may not implement it" You have this completely the wrong way round. A concrete class that declares an interface must implement it, or it will not compile. There's no such requirement that a child class override a virtual method in the parent. 
All this is orthogonal to whether the visibility is public or protected.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the compiler will not allow you to change the access modifiers of a method when overriding it from the parent, so the answer to the question is that by declaring a method as protected within a class, you are only making it available to derived classes (whether abstract or not is a separate concern and doesn't bear on the access level).

Keep in mind, however, that derived class would be free to expose the function in some other way such as calling the protected method from a public one and there is no way to prevent that.

As far as "why" you would have a protected abstract member, a great example can be seen in many implementations of the Template Method pattern.  You may have an abstract base class that describes the structure of an algorithm and leave the specific steps of what happens inside the boundary of each step to derived classes.  In this case, one way to implement would be to declare the base class as abstract, have a public method serve as the "entry point" for the algorithm, and define specific methods used within the algorithm as protected abstract methods to lay out what the responsibility of derived classes will be.  This pattern does a nice job of leaving public only those things that are intended to be consumed by the world, but can present some challenges from a unit testing perspective which are sometimes addressed by raising the visibility of the helper methods from protected to internal.

Comment: My question wasn't around `protected` / `public` but more around giving a child class a way of implementing functionality. That said, any confusion as to `public` / `protected` is more down to bad phrasing of my question and for that, apologies. Your points are good ones and well stated, just not what I was driving at.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the c# language to prevent a derived class from implementing a public version of `OnlyMeOrChildrenCanDoAction`. Even if you mark it as `protected  virtual`, the derived class can use the `new` keyword to cover the method and change its accessibility. For example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
     protected virtual void OnlyMeOrChildrenCanDoAction()
     {
         // leave empty as current class is structural/conceptual
         // but child instances may need it
     }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new void OnlyMeOrChildrenCanDoAction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is public.");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var b = new BaseClass();
        //b.OnlyMeOrChildrenCanDoAction(); //Will not compile

        var d = new DerivedClass();
        d.OnlyMeOrChildrenCanDoAction();  //Look! It's public!
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This is public.
```

Code available on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BOXFTh).

If you want to protect the caller from calling `OnlyMeOrChildrenCanDoAction`, your best bet is for the caller to use only interfaces. If `OnlyMeOrChildrenCanDoAction` isn't in the interface, there is no way a caller could call it, even if a derived class decided to expose it as a public class member. This is good SOLID design anyway.

On the other hand, if you're not so much worried about the caller as you are worried about your own development team doing bad things, perhaps your best option is to use [FxCop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop) or some other source code rules engine integrated into your continuous build process. Developers could still add the method but you could set up a rule to cause it to fail the build if they do so.

Comment: The question wasn't around trying to limit access (though your answer is thorough on that), it was around if there was another way to give a child implementation the option of implementing functionality via a mechanism other than `abstract`, `interface` or `protected virtual`. Based on the answers so far, that's a "no". I appreciate the reasons for the question are esoteric but it centers around why `Finalize` was implemented as it is.